# Grafana field type Transformation outputs incorrect timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, time-series, grafana, amazon-athena

**Task**: I want to transform a bigint data column [which i send from aws athena to grafana] (see picture 1.) to a timestamp which generates my timeseriesdata inside grafana.

**Problem**: My problem is, that after i transform that bigint column (see picture 2.) it shows completly unuseable timeformats like the year 2610.

**How can i solve this problem so i have a correct timestamp format inside my Grafana Instance.**

[1. Dataformat before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1qol.png)

[2. Dataformat after Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q3mC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add one other transformation first.

Grafana is, for some reason, interpreting the data field as a number and, as a result, the transformation is converting the numerical value as the original format is epoch time.

Epoch conversion

Ex. 20220304155105 -> Thu Oct 04 2610 07:09:15 GMT+0000 -> 2610-10-04 09:09:15

Solution

Add another `Convert field type` transformation and convert the data to a `string` before you convert it to time, I think you'll find success.

In summary, you'll need to:

- Add a transformation to convert the data to a string.
- Add a second transformation to convert the string to a time, formatted as you require.

The docs aren't great here, unfortunately.

Take a look at this dashboard for an example: https://play.grafana.org/d/8HOxnCYnk/double-transform?orgId=1&editPanel=2&tab=transform

It includes a quick and dirty CSV mockup of your data so you can play with the transformations a bit.